# Manually printing individual values of char * without looping or incrementing

Tags: c

Is there a way to manually do print elements of *char arrays as hex values without introducing loops or affecting the pointers by incrementation?

It should not add introduce additional variables, change current ones and should be a oneliner `printf/printk/...`

Comment: That doesn't sound "simple" at all. You should add more context to clarify the very strange requirement of not modifying the pointer. If the array length isn't known at compile-time, it's going to be ... difficult to avoid looping.

Comment: What do you mean by "simple" debug prints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below can be used for a reference.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char buf[3] = {0xa, 13, 'a'};
    printf("%x \n", *buf);          # a
    printf("%x \n", *(buf+1));      # d
    printf("%x \n", *(buf+2));      # 61

    printf("%x \n", *buf);          # a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No loops, pointer and size are constant parameters effectively:

```
void fun( char * ptr, uint idx, uint size )
{
    if( idx < size )
    {
        printf( "% 2x\n", ( unsigned char ) ( ptr[idx] ) );
        fun( ptr, 1 + idx, size );
    }
}
```

Example invocation:

```
char ray[] = { 0xca, 0xff, 0xee, 0x00 };
fun( ray, 0, sizeof( ray ) / sizeof( ray[0] ) );
```